# custom link_to - ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, link-to

I have a class *Thingy*, whose objects often need to create links to other websites. So far the only approach working for me is the following:

```
class Thingy < Active:Record::Base
  def makeLink
    result = "<a href=\"someURL"+self.firstProperty+"\">"+self.secondProperty+"</a>"
  end
...
```

Now in any view I could use this link-method as follows

```
thingy.makeLink.html_safe
```

Somehow I feel there should be a much better way. What is the right approach here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the proper approach would be to add a `ThingyHelper` in `app/helpers`

```
def behavior_describing_method_name(thingy)
  link_to thingy.secondProperty, "someUrl#{thingy.firstProperty}"
end
```

Comment: you've got to except the answers when they are resolved. that's how this stackoverflow thingy works